# Prove that a monoid with property $ (a * a' = e) \lor (a' * a = e) $ is a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semigroups, monoid

Let  $(G , *)$, $G \neq \emptyset$ be closed, associative, there is an identity element $ e $ in $ G $ and:
$ (\forall a \in G)(\exists a' \in G) $
$ (a * a' = e) \lor (a' * a = e) $

Prove that G is a group.

---

Let $a * a' = e$  and $ a' * a = b \in G $
$$ b = a' * a / * b $$
$$ b * b = (a' * a) * (a' * a) $$
$$ b * b = a' * (a * a') * a $$
$$ b * b = a' * a = b $$

$$ b * e = b * b $$
$$ (a' * a) * (a * a') = (a' * a) * (a' * a) $$
$$ (a' * a) * e = (a' * a) * (a' * a) $$

Now I can see that:

$$ b * (a' * a) = (a' * a) * b = b \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; b * e = e * b = b $$

But is $ (a' * a) = e $ here? I know that $ (a' * a) $ is an identity element for $\forall b \in G$, but does b represent every element in G? Is this proof valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that
$$b * b = (′∗)∗(′∗)$$
$$ b*b = a' * e * a $$
$$b*b = b$$
Since $b \in G$ we can use the hypothesis and $\exists b' \in G$ such that $b * b' = e$, so

$$b*b* b' = b* b'$$
$$a'a = b = e$$

And this argument is completely general since $a,b$ could be every element of $G$